# Finding maximum size of a finite language accepted by DFA

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $k$ be the size of $Σ$ where $Σ$ is a finite alphabet, and $M$ be a $n$-state Deterministic Finite Automaton over $Σ$. When $L$ is a finite language accepted by $M$, how can the maximum value of $|L|$ be expressed with $n$ and $k$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a lower bound**. How many states are needed to accept $\Sigma^r$?

**Hint for an upper bound**. What is the maximal length of a word of a finite language accepted by an $n$-state DFA?